# DropDown Buttons in a side menu items

Tags: flutter, side-menu, dropdownbutton

I've made a side menu with items but what I need now is to add another sub menu for each item.

What should I do to accomplish that?

```
class CustomListTitle extends StatelessWidget{
    //....
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
      Icon(icon),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16.0
        ),),
      ),
      ],
     ),
    Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want, but If what you want is basically this:
[image]
except inside of you're side menu, then I suggest that you check out [ExpansionPanels](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanel-class.html)